# Configure iwconfig with advanced parameters

Tags: server, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I have a wireless network which is configured in the following way :

- Wireless security as WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- Authentication as PEAP
- CA certificate --> None
- Peap version --> Automatic
- Inner authentication --> MSCHAPv2
- Username --> `<username to be given>`
- Password --> `<password to be given>`

The problem is I have a Ubuntu server 18.04 , where I don't have any UI.
How can I connect from the aforementioned Ubuntu server to this network through only **command line**  ?

Here is output of `lsusub` :

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: i neaver used PEOP authentification, but when it comes to connect to any wifi network via command line i would use `wpa_supplicant` # check `man wpa_supplicant` and `man wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: You might face this bug with WPA-Enterprise/PEAP and no CA cert on 18.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1748839